# Returning last and penultimate values in a table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

**Hello.**

I'm getting to grips with PowerBI and need some guidance on generating three additional columns in a table, which indicate the penultimate and latest quality rating and change in rating for a particular object.

I'm dealing with a huge (and sensitive) dataset, but I've got a mock-example, which is similar to this:

[image]

My requirement is quite complex. What I want (see the image below) is a table which summarises:

1. The Latest Sales Date by Product ID
2. The Latest Quality Rating
3. The Previous Quality Rating
4. A Change column indicating Improvement or Degradation

I've tried various techniques found in forums online to try and get the latest and penultimate sales date including a combination of the CALCULATE and MAX functions. I've managed to generate a column which shows the latest date for each ID, but not the actual value itself. I'm stuck and some help would be really appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define your quality level, I made a simple table for this.
[image]

Ensure there is a relation in your tables
[image]

Add a new column (Rating) to your Sales table:

```
Rating = RELATED(Rating[Rate])
```

Add a new Column (Previous Sales Date), Note that this column can be empty when there is not previous date:

```
Previous Sales Date = 
var area = Sales[Area]
var prod_Id = Sales[Product ID]
var last_Date = Sales[Sales Date]
return CALCULATE(MAXX(Sales;Sales[Sales Date]);FILTER(Sales;Sales[Area] = area && Sales[Product ID] = prod_Id && Sales[Sales Date] < last_Date))
```

Add a Column (Previous Rating), also this can be empty

```
Previous Rating = 
var area = Sales[Area]
var prod_Id = Sales[Product ID]
var prev_Date = Sales[Previous Sales Date]
return LOOKUPVALUE(Sales[Rating];Sales[Area];area;Sales[Product ID] ;prod_Id; Sales[Sales Date] ;prev_Date)
```

Last column will be the (Change) column:

```
Change = IF(ISBLANK(Sales[Previous Rating]);"NA"; IF(Sales[Previous Rating] < Sales[Rating]; "Improvement";if(Sales[Previous Rating]> Sales[Rating];"Degraded";"Same")))
```

End result:

[image]

This table you can filter to your liking and make the visibles you want.